# How to fill a custom shape using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, fill, uibezierpath

I want to create a custom shape into a `UIView` by drawing it myself using a `UIBezierPath` object and render it in `drawRect:`.
So far I managed to create the shape and stroke it so it is drawn on screen exactly how I want it to be. However I can't fill it properly. Here is the code so far:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.f);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth:2.f];
    [path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];

    // Stroke top left arc
    //[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(20.f, 2.f)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(10.f, 10.f) radius:5.f startAngle:3*M_PI/2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:0];

    // Stroke bottom left arc
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(10.f, 50.f) radius:5.f startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/2 clockwise:0];

    // Stroke bottom line
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.f, 55.f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(60.f, 55.f)];

    // Stroke bottom arc
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(80.f, 55.f)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(71.f, 65.f) radius:15.f startAngle:degreesToRadians(315) endAngle:degreesToRadians(215) clockwise:1];

    // Stroke bottom right arc
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(80.f, 55.f)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(80.f, 50.f) radius:5.f startAngle:M_PI/2 endAngle:0 clockwise:0];

    // Stroke top right arc
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(80.f, 10.f) radius:5.f startAngle:0 endAngle:3*M_PI/2 clockwise:0];

    // Close path
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(80.f, 5.f)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10.f, 5.f)];

    [path stroke];
    [path fill];
}
```

Stroke works as expected, but the fill only fills portions on the `path`, instead of filling the entire `path`. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `usesEvenOddFillRule` property of your path

Comment: @Gonzo, nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
Just needed to get rid of moveToPoint: calls since they create subpaths and so the filling will only affect the new subpaths. And finally called closePath.

Now my path is continuous and the fill works for the entire shape.

Edited code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth:2.f];
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];

// Stroke top left arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(10.f, 10.f) radius:5.f startAngle:3*M_PI/2 endAngle:M_PI clockwise:0];

// Stroke bottom left arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(10.f, 50.f) radius:5.f startAngle:M_PI endAngle:M_PI/2 clockwise:0];

// Stroke bottom arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(71.f, 65.f) radius:15.f startAngle:degreesToRadians(215) endAngle:degreesToRadians(315) clockwise:0];

// Stroke bottom right arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(80.f, 50.f) radius:5.f startAngle:M_PI/2 endAngle:0 clockwise:0];

// Stroke top right arc
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(80.f, 10.f) radius:5.f startAngle:0 endAngle:3*M_PI/2 clockwise:0];

// Close path
[path closePath];

[path fill];
[path stroke];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Remove all your

```
- (void)moveToPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

methods except the first one because it is a continuous path you don't need it.

It is highly recommended to close the path by calling the method `- (void)closePath` because you are having 3 pixel gap.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the method

```
- (void)closePath
```

at the end to close your UIBezierPath.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ABFORCE, which is an answer because the person is not closing the path and having 3 pixel gap. Therefore he/she has to close it.

Comment: @Goppinath An answer must provide more explanation and clarify the problem, This is a SO rule!